# Can I declare a pixel argument without using PX?

Tags: less, mixins

This is my mixin for Margin Left:

```
.mL (@pixels) {
    margin-left: @{pixels}px;
}
```

And this is how i call it:

```
#menu {
    .mL(124);
}
```

This outputs a syntax error. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with escaped string interpolation:

```
.mL (@pixels) {
    margin-left: ~"@{pixels}px";
}
```

A cleaner approach may be to add `0px` to your variable:

```
.mL (@pixels) {
    margin-left: @pixels + 0px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome that you found that second cleaner, smarter way of doing it. Thanks again!